# Version control: registered or unregistered?

Tags: vc

I'm a bit confused when writing code using the VC interface. After executing the following commands in the shell (committing a dummy file `~/test/file` in a fresh git repo `~/test`):

```sh
cd
mkdir test
cd test
git init
touch file
git add file
git commit -am "test"
```

I end up in a situation in which Emacs `(vc-state "~/test/file")` evaluate to `unregistered` but `(vc-registered "~/test/file")` reports the converse as it evaluates to `t`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I'm supposed to be on the buffer. Hence, the following snippet

```
(with-current-buffer 
  (find-file-noselect "~/test/file") 
  (vc-state "~/test/file"))
```

is evaluated to `up-to-date`.